# Why google map does not work after gradle, kotlin, libraries updates

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

GoogleMap does not work on some devices like: `samsung a35 i samsung s10` after updating `gradle` to 8.2.2 and api target to `34`. I don't have any errors. Everything works on some devices with API 34 and some does not work. Even I had a situation that it stopped work on my Android 30 and then after reinstall it starts working...
I have upgraded libraries and that is my actual:

```
    const val googleServicesPlugin = "com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1"
```

```
object Google {

    private const val mapServicesVersion = "18.2.0"
    const val mapServices = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$mapServicesVersion"

    private const val placesVersion = "3.4.0"
    const val places = "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:$placesVersion"

    private const val materialVersion = "1.4.0"
    const val material = "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"

    private const val gmsLocationVersion = "21.2.0"
    const val gmsLocation = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$gmsLocationVersion"
}
```

```
    const val composeVersion = "1.6.4"
    const val composeCompilerVersion = "1.5.7"
```

Additionally my `places API` stopped work as well.

```
    private suspend fun searchUsingAutocompletePredictions(): List<PlaceSuggestion> {
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            placesClient
                .findAutocompletePredictions(createSearchRequest())
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    continuation.resume(it.autocompletePredictions.mapToPlaceSuggestions())
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    continuation.resume(emptyList())
                }
                .addOnCanceledListener {
                    continuation.resume(emptyList())
                }
        }
    }
```

This method doesn't work. Don't have any errors.
To be more weird about this problem, on debug mod it worked on these devices.

This is my proguard

```
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.** { *; }
```

```
Box(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            ) {
                GoogleMap(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
                    onMapClick = { },
                ) {
                    state.darkStoreAreaList.forEach {
                        Polygon(
                            points = it,
                            fillColor = Color(0x1A000000),
                            strokeColor = Color(0xFF2E2E2E),
                            strokeWidth = 3f
                        )
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details as to what you mean by "not working" that would help the community pinpoint what might be the cause of the issue.